# Ruby kind_of? and is_a? returning false for a subclass

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to take advantage of the ruby methods `kind_of?` and `is_a?`. As I understand it they are synonyms of one another.

I have an object of class `Child`. A call to `Child.ancestors` gives back an array list this `[Child, #<Module>, Parent, ...]`.  However a call to `Child.new.is_a?(Parent)` or `Child.new.kind_of?(Parent)` returns false.

Calling `Child.ancestors[2].new.is_a?(Parent)` also returns false. I can't seem to figure out why this would be considering calling `Parent.new.is_a?(Parent)` returns true as it clearly should.

These classes all eventually descend from `ActiveResource::Base` if that has anything to do with it.

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MyModule 
  def self.my_method(obj) 
    if obj.is_a?(Parent) 
      puts 'Hello' 
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def my_method
    self.class.my_method(self)
  end
end

a = Child.new 
a.my_method
```

Comment: Can you post your class definitions please?

Comment: `class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
    include MyModule
    
    def self.my_method(obj)
      if obj.is_a?(Parent)
        puts 'Hello'
      end
    end
end

class Child < Parent
  def my_method
    self.class.my_method(self)
  end
end

a = Child.new
a.my_method`

Answer (score -1):

```
class Parent
  def self.my_method(obj)
    if obj.is_a?(Parent)
      puts 'IS A PARENT'
    else
      puts 'IS NOT A PARENT'
    end
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  def my_method
    self.class.my_method(self)
  end
end

a = Child.new
a.my_method
```

Note I dropped the AR and included module, but the above prints out "IS A PARENT" for me.  Ruby 1.8.7 on osx.